# Solving a recurrence relation with n squared

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have trouble solving the following recurrence:

$$a_{1}=1, a_{n}=a_{n-1}\cdot n^{2}$$ for $n>1$. It seems somewhat untypical to me, could you give me some general advice on dealing with such examples?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this recurrence?

Comment: What does $a_n$ look like if you successively apply the recurrence relation?

Comment: Work out the first four or five terms of the progression by hand, and you will see a pattern (it is very simple). This is **always** the best place to start. Intuition can be confirmed by algebra, but algebra unconstrained by intuition wanders round in circles and goes nowhere.

Comment: Thank you @MartinKochanski for your informative suggestion and others for putting it brilliantly into practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a_2=2^2$, $a_3= 2^23^2$. In general, $a_n = (n!)^2$.

You can check by induction - true for $n=1$. If true for $n$, $a_{n+1}= (n!)^2(n+1)^2 = ((n+1)!)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Alteratively to the excellent answer by @Vaneet, you can take the logarithm and define $\ln(a_n)=b_n$ to turn the product in a sum.

$$\ln(a_n)=\ln(a_{n-1})+2\ln(n),$$ or

$$b_n=b_{n-1}+2\ln(n).$$

With $b_0=0$, the solution of this classical recurrence is

$$b_n=2\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)$$ i.e.

$$a_n=\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=n^2 a_{n-1}\\
&=n^2(n-1)^2a_{n-2}\\
&=n^2(n-1)^2(n-2)^2a_{n-3}\\
&\vdots\\
&=n^2(n-1)^2(n-2)^2\cdots 2^2\overbrace{a_1}^{=1}\\
&=[n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2\cdot 1]^2\\
&=(n!)^2\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$